# Why can't I uninstall node with homebrew?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I'm on a MacBook running MacOS 12.6.1
I'm trying to uninstall node. But its not working.
How can I fix this?

See the output below:

```
% node -v
v14.21.3

% which node
/opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin/node

% ls -al /opt/homebrew/opt/node@14
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  25 Mar  6 21:26 /opt/homebrew/opt/node@14 -> ../Cellar/node@14/14.21.3

% brew uninstall node --force
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%

% which node
/opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin/node

% node -v
v14.21.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have version [`node@14`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node@14) installed, which is different from the regular [`node`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node) formula.

```
brew uninstall node@14
```

Should do the trick.